# Neo4j Cypher query: Find node by input path

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a graph that contains a tree hierarchy of the system. In this graph, one root has indexed label 'MainRoot', all other relationships are type 'hasParent'.
I would like to construct a query that would have list of nodes names (=inputPath) as an input and return the node at the end of query.

Now i have this working example, which last returned item is the specified node with the name "java", as I want (located in Root/src/main/java):

```
// Input
WITH ["Root", "src", "main", "java"] AS inputPath
// Iterator
UNWIND range(0,size(inputPath)-2) AS i
MATCH (parent)<-[:hasParent]-(child)
WHERE (parent.name = inputPath[i]) AND (child.name = inputPath[i+1])
RETURN child
```

However, I would like to somehow let the query now, that the first parent element of the query is the node with the indexed label 'MainRoot'.

1. I expect it would be more efficient since it will now, in which node to start the traversal.
2. If I have structure e.g. Root/example/Root/src/main/java, the query would also return this 'java' node, which I obviously don't want to return.

Any idea how could I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the shortest way I could think of.

```
WITH ["Root", "src", "main", "java"] AS inputPath     
MATCH path=(mainRoot)<-[:hasParent*]-(child)
WHERE LENGTH(path) = SIZE(inputPath)-1
AND [n IN nodes(path) | n.name] = inputPath
RETURN path
```

Comment: Thanks, this one prints desired results, however I think it could hit performance issues for long inputPaths, because the REDUCE step necessarily goes to all nodes of depth inputPath-1. 

I mean this algorithm would traverse all the way to the node e.g. 'Root/docs/sth/html', even it could realize that the node 'Root/docs' isn't in the path and so it could skip the whole subtree of 'docs' node.

Comment: @Lukasmp3 I fully agree..  probably it would be possible to optimize this. But I thought, let's give good ol' Lukas some input that would help him further. When I have time, I'll give it another look.

Comment: I added another approach, probably performing better. Don't see at this moment that I can avoid the REDUCE() because you have to be sure that you do the comparison in the correct order.

Comment: I overlooked the most simple approach  :)

Comment: Thanks, this one looks good to me :) Btw, what exactly this (AND [n IN nodes(path) | n.name] = inputPath) command does? I couldn't find it or missed it in the Cypher docs...

Comment: @Lukasmp3 see https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-refcard/current/  and look under  "List Expressions' where you find [x IN list | x.prop]  Now please accept my answer  ;)